# Calculator app crashing with java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have developed one Calcualtor application. the application is unfortunately failing to launch with exception as "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. Not Sure what exactly is this issue and what is causing the issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.getChildDrawingOrder(ViewPager.java:681)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.buildOrderedChildList(ViewGroup.java:3314)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3189)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2259)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:587)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

activity_calculator_Port .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorPadViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pad_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/pad_numeric" />
            <include layout="@layout/pad_operator_one_col" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/pad_advanced" />

    </shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorPadViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Log Cat File says when running the app

```
10-03 23:46:01.949  18129-18129/shashank_balaganchi.calculator E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'java.util.Locale$Builder', referenced from method shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorNumericPadLayout.onFinishInflate
10-03 23:46:01.949  18129-18129/shashank_balaganchi.calculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: shashank_balaganchi.calculator, PID: 18129
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shashank_balaganchi.calculator/shashank_balaganchi.calculator.Calculator}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
            at shashank_balaganchi.calculator.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:124)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
            at shashank_balaganchi.calculator.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:124)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/pad_button_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003f
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2139)
            at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:348)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3558)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
            at shashank_balaganchi.calculator.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:124)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: invalid drawable tag ripple
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:935)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
            at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2515)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2135)
            at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:348)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3558)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:842)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
            at shashank_balaganchi.calculator.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:124)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/display_background_color"
    android:elevation="4dip">

    <shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorEditText
        android:id="@+id/formula"
        style="@style/DisplayEditTextStyle.Formula"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/display_formula_text_color" />

    <shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorEditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        style="@style/DisplayEditTextStyle.Result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/formula"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/display_result_text_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Padadvance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorPadLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pad_advanced"
    style="@style/PadLayoutStyle.Advanced"
    android:background="@color/pad_advanced_background_color">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fun_sin"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fun_sin"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/fun_sin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fun_cos"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fun_cos"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/fun_cos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fun_tan"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fun_tan"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/fun_tan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fun_ln"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fun_ln"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/fun_ln" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fun_log"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fun_log"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/fun_log" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/op_fact"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_op_fact"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/op_fact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/const_pi"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_const_pi"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/const_pi" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/const_e"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_const_e"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/const_e" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/op_pow"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_op_pow"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/op_pow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lparen"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_lparen"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/lparen" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rparen"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_rparen"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/rparen" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/op_sqrt"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Advanced"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_op_sqrt"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/op_sqrt" />

</shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorPadLayout>
```

padnumeric.xml

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorNumericPadLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pad_numeric"
    style="@style/PadLayoutStyle.Numeric"
    android:background="@color/pad_numeric_background_color"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_7"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_8"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_9"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_4"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_5"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_6"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_1"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_2"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_3"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dec_point"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit_0"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eq"
        style="@style/PadButtonStyle.Numeric.Equals"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_eq"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/eq" />

</shashank_balaganchi.calculator.CalculatorNumericPadLayout>
```

Comment: pad_button_background.xml <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/pad_button_ripple_color" />

Comment: There's no NullPointerException, here. Your error is `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/pad_button_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003f`

Comment: The file is already there. But Still i am not sure what is causing the issue. Do i need to clean the project again??

Answer (score 1):

```
res/drawable/pad_button_background.xml
```

Is missing for resource with id:  #0x7f02003f

Comment: I think this is not the issue. Please see the above comments for the missing resource

Comment: This is exactly your issue. Your app cannot find this resource, so you probably have some structure / reference problem in your calculator.

Comment: how to resolve this.. Will clean up help this?? or some other process is there??

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by clean up. You need to debug and check why he cannot find the path. Based on what you have provided is hard to say why it cannot find that resource.

Comment: @SHASHANKBalaganchi Were you able to figure out the error?